# SQL Server linked server error 7303 to Access database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-server

I've performed multiple searches and read numerous pages and tried loads of different configurations and nothing seems to solve a nuisance problem we have.  We have a SQL server (2008 R2 v10.50.4000) that has several linked servers to several different access databases on a different server.  They are all set up using UNC paths and they work...for a time.

At some point, something happens and then we can no longer access the databases and the only way I have found to solve this is to restart the SQL server service, which obviously isn't ideal in a production environment.  This is the exact error message we get when we try to access it:

OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "*HIDDEN*" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\servername\path01\path02\path03\databasename.mdb'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.".

Yet it works absolutely fine again if I restart the SQL Server service, so I know the settings are correct.  I strongly suspect it has something to do with the Microsoft ACE driver because they all (the Access database linked servers) stop working at the same time - even though they all look at different files.

At this point I'm willing to try anything.

Comment: Are any other users connected to the Access DBs? And why are linking SQL Server to Access DBs instead of Access tables to SQL Server? I suspect that's the root of your problem.

Comment: Yes, many users, and we are extracting information out of the access databases in order to process information more efficiently in SQL.  We have an application that uses the Access databases and is too large to rewrite now, so we have to keep the Access databases currently.

Comment: In that case, I would lean towards an SSIS, PDI (Pentaho Data Integration), custom scripts, or some other ETL solution to sync data from Access to SQL Server periodically. The issue you're seeing is common with Access databases and I know of no way around it.

Comment: Okay, I'll investigate those other options you've suggested, thank you very much for your advice.